# Fat-Free framework with Smart

Tags: php, smarty, template-engine, fat-free-framework

We am working on a application using Fat-Free PHP framework, and we wish to use Smart as the template engine.

We've followed the http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/installing.smarty.basic.tpl.

We run the Smarty test, without errors, but now when we want to display a template via Smarty through Fat-Free PHP framework, we just gets error from Fat-Free.

This is the route

```
    $f3->route('GET /', function($f3) {
        $smarty->assign('name','Ned');
        $smarty->debugging = true;
        $smarty->display('index.tpl');
    });
```

Can anyone guide me the right way?

Comment: Undefined variable: smarty. This is the index file (router)

Comment: Why not just use mustache with fat free framework? which allows extending.

Comment: @GeoffreyMureithi .. Care to explain some more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the sulotion, had to include the smarty variable.